# Show MessageBox immediately in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, winforms

Is there any way to have a messagebox immediately pop up when a form opens? I just want to display a short message about how to use the form when it opens. I tried

```
private void myForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult dialogOpen = MessageBox.Show("Use the navigation menu to get started.", "Welcome!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: yes there is definitely a way you should do a google search on 
[Form.DialogResult Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) also read up on winforms event life cycle in regards to the order in which a form is loaded shown etc... here is where you need to read @MorganPeters [Order of Events  in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Try using the `Shown` event instead of the `Load`.

Comment: Just my 2 cents from a UX point of view: being hit by MessageBox right away before I had the chance to do anything at all would make me want to rip my eyes out with a rusty fork. Surely there must be a gentler/nicer way to give hints the user? A colored label, maybe?

Comment: @s. m. you're definitely right! I was mostly just trying things out, and wanted to see how it worked. I eventually decided to add a "help" menu item instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't work in Form_Load. Definitely try doing as others have pointed out by putting it beneath form initialization.

Though, given that you're just showing a message box, I don't think there is any reason to store the result, so a simple `MessageBox.Show(message);` Should do the trick.

As @s.m. said, from a UX point of view, having a notification thrown in your face as soon as the app starts would be very obnoxious, at least if you have it EVERY time. Personally, I would create a boolean Settings variable, set it to true the first time the message is displayed, and only display it when the setting is false, i.e. the first time the message is displayed.

```
private boolean splashShown = Properties.Settings.Default.splashShown;

private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!splashShown)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("message");
        myForm.Properties.Settings.Default.splashShown = true;
        myForm.Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
}
```

And set up the `splashShown` Setting in your form properties.

If the problem is that your `Form_Load()` method isn't actually attached to your `Form.Load()` event, you can double click the form window in the designer and it will automatically created the `Form_Load()` base method for you and attach it to the `Form.Load()` event

Answer (score 4):

Showing a MessageBox during Form_Load works just fine for me.  I literally copy/pasted the code from your original post, and it worked.  I'm on .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows 8.1.

Are you sure your Load event handler is getting called?  Perhaps the it's not hooked up to the Load event properly.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason to use the Load method of the form? If not you could to it in the constructor of form. If you want it to show up immediately after your form loads, you should do it in the constructor after the form is initialized. It should look something like this:

```
public partial class myForm : Form
{
    public myForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DialogResult dialogOpen = MessageBox.Show("Use the navigation menu to get started.", "Welcome!", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

The constructor (`public myForm()`) and the `InitializeComponent();` should be automatically added to the form by Visual Studio after creating it.

Comment: While this solution may work, approach doing non-initialization operations with caution.

Comment: In this case, showing a simple MessageBox shouldn't be a problem at all or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Form_Load event occurs before the form is really visible.
I use:

```
static private bool splashShown = false;
    private void Form1_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!splashShown)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("message");
            splashShown = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I have used this and it works fine. App start brings up messagebox first before all else.

```
InitializeComponent();
MessageBox.Show("put your message here");
```

Comment: You shouldn't show it in the constructor, use the Form events like Form_OnShown